# How to replace characters in Spark-dataframe like python pandas-dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe in spark like this :

```py
+--------------------+--------------------+
|               tag_1|               tag_2|
+--------------------+--------------------+
|[music,rhythm,3ye...|[{"tag_id":1400,"...|
|                [""]|[{"tag_id":1464,"...|
|[picture,language...|                [""]|
+--------------------+--------------------+
```

Question 1:
Is there any solution to display it all not "..."?

Question 2:
How to repalce[""] by "Na"?

Question 3:
How to remove "[","]" in column-tag_1 and column-tag_2; and remove [{"tag_id": and "tag_name":" in column-tag_2?

How to get the same results in spark? How to deal with dataframe columns like pandas?

if in pandas, I'll use regular expression like this:

```py
def replace_1(x):
    pa_1 = re.compile(r"\[\"\"\]")

    x = pa_1.sub("Na", x)
    return x.strip()

def replace_2(x):
    pa_1 = re.compile(r"[\[\]\"{}]")
    pa_2 = re.compile(r'tag_id:')
    pa_3 = re.compile(r'tag_name:')    

    x = pa_1.sub("", x)
    x = pa_2.sub("", x)
    x = pa_3.sub("", x)
    return x.strip()

df_1.tag_1 = df_1.tag_1.apply(replace_1).apply(replace_2)
df_1.tag_2 = df_1.tag_2.apply(replace_1).apply(replace_2)
```

I tried:

```py
def stemmize_loc(word: String): String ={
word.replaceAll("[", "")
}

def udfstemmize_loc = udf(stemmize_loc _)

val df1 = df.withColumn("tag_1",udfstemmize_loc(col("tag_1")))

df1.show()
```

This didn't work~

So, how to remove the characters and get the final result in spark like this:

```py
+------------------------------+--------------------+
|                         tag_1|               tag_2|
+------------------------------+--------------------+
|       music,rhythm,3years,boy|          1400,music|
|                            Na|   1464,comunication|
|picture,language,4years,myself|                  Na|
+------------------------------+--------------------+
```

Thank you very much~~